# Is it possible to highlight the current "active selection" area in the Mac App Store window when using keyboard navigation?

Tags: keyboard, mac-appstore, accessibility

I find it easier to use the keyboard to navigate around my Mac.

Most of the apps I use work OK with keyboard shortcuts as they tend to highlight the currently active control.

However, I find the Mac App Store difficult to use with the keyboard as it does not highlight controls as I move around the app's window.

To give an example…

1. I launch the Mac App Store.
2. I hit CMD + F to enter the search box. (I know the search box is active as it's highlighted with a blue border.)
3. I type in 'Pages' and hit enter.
4. The search results appear.
5. I hit TAB to move out of the search box to the search results area, but as I move around using TAB, SHIFT + TAB, etc., the active control is not highlighted.

To be clear, I can "move around" using the keyboard without a problem, but as nothing is highlighted I don't know "where I am".

I've checked through the Accessibility Preference Pane in case there's something there that can help, but can't find anything that might enable highlighting.

I'd be grateful if anyone knows a way to enable highlighting of the currently selected control in the Mac App Store app, whether that's by changing a setting in the Terminal, by using a third party "tweaker" app, etc.

I'm currently running OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 (14C109).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

added as answer to provide picture…

Do you have "All controls" selected in System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard ?

ahhh… I see what you mean. Enter will highlight 'Install App' but before that there is no indication of where you are.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I do have all controls selected but, as you've spotted, it brings no joy. Oh, woe is me and there was much gnashing of the teeth and bother and such.